# Installing a different php version for a subdomain

Tags: centos, php, version, cpanel

I have a cPanel dedicated server installed with PHP 5.2.17. I need to use php 5.3 version for my subdomain and the directory needed php.5.3 is `/home/website30/public_html/blog/`.

Can anyone provide the step by step installation of php 5.3 for this issue and the steps that bind PHP 5.3 with the directory  `/home/website30/public_html/blog/`?

Answer (score 1):

If your requirements permit you to have the subdomain be a different cPanel account, I'd recommend using CloudLinux and its PHP Selector for this.  I think you can do an in-place upgrade of CentOS to CloudLinux and it also integrates with cPanel.

This is especially recommended if you're going to be running PHP versions which no longer receive security updates such as the ones you're wanting to run (5.2 and 5.3) because you can use its CageFS functionality to isolate one site from another so if one gets hacked the other has protection.